# Docker keep powershell environment changes

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I am writing a dockerfile and I do:

```
RUN Set-DNSClient -InterfaceIndex 5 -ConnectionSpecificSuffix my.dns.suffix
```

If I do other things within this `RUN`, the connection suffix will persist, and I can use unc paths, but if I use a separate `RUN` it will *forget* it and I will have to reset the `DNSClient`.  This also happens when I docker `RUN` the image itself, which defeats the purpose I believe..

Is there something I'm missing to keep that setting in each layer/in the container when I start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I have found a workaround for this, basically you want to create a powershell profile at the start of the container, which will get run everytime the `RUN` command is used..

To do this, I did the following :

> RUN mkdir C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell ;
>
> RUN New-Item C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 -Type file -Value 'Set-DNSClient -InterfaceIndex 5 -ConnectionSpecificSuffix my.dns.suffix ;'

This will make sure that everytime I run a command it will execute the Set-DNSClient on opening a powershell session.

Hope this helps someone.